# Clickhouse is not starting

Tags: clickhouse

After installing clickhouse using rpm packages ,we got an issue with starting of clickhouse.

Below are the steps we followed for installation:

Download all the required packages on one particular location for eg: /opt/clickhouse using below commands

```
# mkdir /opt/clickhouse
# cd /opt/clickhouse # wget http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/rpm/stable/x86_64/clickhouse-common-static-18.12.17-2.x86_64.rpm #wget http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/rpm/stable/x86_64/clickhouse-server-base-18.12.17-2.x86_64.rpm #wget http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/rpm/stable/x86_64/clickhouse-server-common-18.12.17-2.noarch.rpm #wget http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/rpm/stable/x86_64/clickhouse-server-18.12.17-2.noarch.rpm #wget http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/rpm/stable/x86_64/clickhouse-client-18.12.17-2.noarch.rpm
```

2. Now the above 5 packages will be available in the given location. Then we have to install the packages one after the other in the below order with the following commands.

   ```
   # rpm -ivh clickhouse-common-static-18.12.17-2.x86_64.rpm
   # rpm -ivh clickhouse-server-base-18.12.17-2.x86_64.rpm
   # rpm -ivh clickhouse-server-common-18.12.17-2.noarch.rpm
   # rpm -ivh clickhouse-server-18.12.17-2.noarch.rpm
   # rpm -ivh clickhouse-client-18.12.17-2.noarch.rpm
   ```

Below is the error message.

systemctl status clickhouse-server

> clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big
>   data) Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service;
>   disabled; vendor preset: disabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
>   since Mon 2019-07-08 19:36:24 +08; 54min ago Process: 23939
>   ExecStart=/etc/init.d/clickhouse-server
>   --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml (code=exited, status=2)

Please help us

Comment: Could you start the server by calling *sudo service clickhouse-server start* (see official dox [CH Launch](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/getting_started/#launch))? Please, provide the server-logs from */var/log/clickhouse-server/*.

Comment: Try debuggigng with Clickhouse's troubleshooting process: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/troubleshooting/

Comment: hey @vladimir tried but no luck. the Logs are also notgenerating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me by using the below command and the logs are also generating now:

`sudo -u clickhouse clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`

Comment: is it running as a service?

Answer (score 0):

The following command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo ./clickhouse install
```

This command rebuilds damaged or lost clickhouse files